# How to access data-value in a selectbox during onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am working with selectbox with javascript onchange event like below ,

```
<select onchange="changeprice(this);" >
    <option value="" selected="">Please select an option</option>
    <option value="17" data-operator="+" data-differ="0.00">2 Tons ( + $0.00 )</option>
    <option value="18" data-operator="-" data-differ="125.00">5 Tons ( - $125.00 )</option>
</select>
```

I managed to call function without problem, But during the event i wish to get the data-attribute instead of the value , and I can't get it to work as expect
Below are my current javascript

```
<script>
function changeprice($this){

alert("test");//successfully alerted
alert($this.data-differ);//no respond
alert($this.data("operator"));//no respond
alert($this.data("differ"));//no respond

};
</script>
```

Please advise

Comment: @CasBloem I have tried $($this).data("differ") but it giving me undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do :

```
<script>
function changeprice(element){

var op = $(element).find("option:selected").data("operator")
var diff = $(element).find("option:selected").data("differ")

};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks your code worked with little change , I don't understand the different but It fix the work for me 

i have to change element to $element

Answer (score 0):

You can gte the different attributes and the value like so:

```
$($this).find(':selected').attr('data-operator');
$($this).find(':selected').attr('data-differ');
$($this).find(':selected').val();
```

Answer (score -1):

I will suppose you're using jQuery. If so, you can access the data attribute using

```
$($this).data("differ")
```

Without jQuery, it could look like

```
// For newer browsers
$this.dataset.differ

// For older IE's, check http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset where you need to use this solution
$this.getAttribute("data-differ")
```